# I need help in finding an average rating of all better products

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
id  year category_id    rating  avg_better
```

need help in finding the average rating of all better products

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please add more details to your post? If you are not sure how to ask, see [Asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information. This will help us to understand you and your question/problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *,
 ( select avg(rating) 
   from mytab as t2
   where t2.year = t1.year     -- same year
     and t2.rating > t1.rating -- better rating
 ) as avg_better
from mytab as t1
```

Comment: Hi dnoeth , thank you for the solution. If instead of NULL can we make it Not Available

Comment: When you want `n/a` you must cast the result to a VarChar and use `coalesce` or `isnull`: `isnull(convert(varchar, (select avg(rating).... as avg_better)), 'n/a')`

Comment: when i try to convert it is showing me error. Can you please help out with the updated query

Comment: Hi dnoeth, my issues is resolved . Thank you